# What is the difference between a single underscore before a class property and @property without setters?

Tags: python

I understand that python doesn't have true private class properties, and we can assign an underscore before a `_<property>` to indicate weak protection. It also seems if we use the `@property` decorator without a setter, others won't be able to change the value of this property.

So my question is, if the above statement is true, why do we need to have the single underscore when we can just disable others to change the value? What is the difference? As someone who's new to python programming, I appreciate your time and patience.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The leading underscore convention tells readers of your code that the variable is an implementation details that should not be relied upon.  The variable is "private" in the sense that it is a class internal that you do not want to be used by client code.

Managing an attribute with just a getter property isn't marking it as *private*, it's marking it as *public* but *read-only*. It's telling client code that it can depend on the attribute's existence, but cannot change its value.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that because python allows arbitrary binding that a `property` without a setter can still indeed be set with little obvious difference to the user.

```
In [4]: class Foo:
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         return 1
   ...:

In [5]: foo = Foo()

In [6]: foo.bar
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: foo.bar = 2

In [8]: foo.bar
Out[8]: 2
```

The `@property.setter` is for *computed* setting of properties - like data type conversion of something along these lines. Using the protected convention of a leading underscore would be recommended for what you are describing as just because you do not implement `.setter`, does not prevent users from perhaps trying to set your properties for you.

Comment: I can only reproduce this behaviour using old-style (classic) classes in Python2.  Using new style classes in Python2, or Python3 classes results in `AttributeError: can't set attribute`